# Is it possible to have two href links (phone number and website links) based on screen size? html/css

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, href, tel

```
<a href="contact.html" href="tel:5555555555">Contact</a>
```

I am trying to create a contact button that will take the user to a website link if the user is not on a mobile screen. However, if the user is on a screen smaller than say 1280 pixels ie. `@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {...`then I want the contact button to call the number in the link.

Either href that I have there works fine but I'm trying to get both based on screen size. Is there a way to make this possible?

EDIT:

```
.button {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15)), url("images/bg01.png");
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15)), url("images/bg01.png");
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15)), url("images/bg01.png");
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.15)), url("images/bg01.png");
    background-color: darkgreen;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    line-height: 2.75em;
    min-width: 9em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: -0.025em;
}

.button:hover {
        background-color: green;
        color: #fff !important;
    }
.button:active {
        background-color: green;
        color: #fff;
    }

#banner header .button {
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-left: 1em;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via CSS Media Queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

So basically, you'll have two links:

```css
.visible-on-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.visible-on-desktop {
  display: inline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .visible-on-mobile {
    display: inline;
  }
  .visible-on-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="visible-on-mobile">
    <a href="tel:0000000000" class="button">Phone</a>
</div>

<div class="visible-on-desktop">
    <a href="mailto:hi@example.com" class="button">Email</a>
</div>
```

This will show the Phone link when the device width is less than or equal to 640px otherwise, the email link will be shown.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there any way to integrate it with a prior coded button? I put the button in the edit

Comment: it works but, the button turns into just an underlined word

Comment: Its because there are no css styles applied to the link. Try using Bootstrap or any other framework, or write your own CSS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: @DanielG Oh, I didn't look at the edited part. In your case you just need to add `<a href="..." class="button">...</a>` for both the HREFs

Comment: When I use `class="visible-on-mobile button"` and `class="visible-on-desktop button"` it ends up showing both buttons at the same time :(

Comment: @DanielG Okay! Its happening because you have `display: inline-block` property in your `.button` class. The display property is getting over written of both classes. Updated my answer to fix that.